# How many times is "align" processed?

Tags: align, write

Consider the following MWE which writes the word "Cat" to a file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\datei
\immediate\openout\datei=Beispiel.txt
\begin{align*}
a+b &=c \\ \immediate\write\datei{Cat}
c+d &= 88+ 9
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Actually, this writes the word "Cat" twice (I have more complicated examples, where it is written four times).

1. Can I determine how many times is an align processed?
2. Can I somehow ensure that the writing command is only called once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`amsmath` uses the conditional `\ifmeasuring@` which is true in the first steps when things are measured and false during the "typesetting step". So you can say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\alignwrite}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@\else
    \write#1{#2}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

and `\immediate\alignwrite\datei{Cat}` will be executed only on the "typesetting step".

Here's the complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\alignwrite}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@\else
    \write#1{#2}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newwrite\datei
\immediate\openout\datei=Beispiel.txt
\begin{align*}
a+b &=c \\ \immediate\write\datei{Cat}
c+d &= 88+ 9
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a+b &=c \\ \immediate\alignwrite\datei{Dog}
c+d &= 88+ 9
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The contents of `Beispiel.txt` is

```
Cat
Cat
Dog
```

This uses the fact that `\immediate` which is not followed by `\write` or `\closeout` is ignored, but it expands the following token to see what really follows.

Comment: Can I rely on \ifmeasuring@ being false everywhere OUTSIDE a math environment? Then I could include your \alignwrite in commands which can be used everywhere in the document.

Comment: @JFMeier `amsmath` always does `\begingroup\measuring@true`, so the conditional is set to true inside a group (and no `\global` is used in this context). So you should be safe.